# Node addon для electron

Tags: node.js, electron

Всем пример, у меня маленький node addon. Я его билжу через node-gyp

[image: дерево файлов]

Я использую electron, а конкретно vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder

Не могу найти в документации, как мне, когда я билжу электрон (vue-cli-service electron:build -mwl), так же сбилдить под все платформы аддон?

Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так как никакой инфы не нашел. Взял пример с других плагинов.

Создал модуль из папки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

npm init сам добавил файл gypfile (видимо нашел binding.gyp и добавил)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

index.js в аддоне

```js
const addonPaste = require('./build/Release/paste.node');

module.exports = {
  paste: addonPaste.paste,
};
```

после чего вы можете заиспользовать в приложении

```js
import { paste } from 'addons-cpp';

paste();
```